# Is there an open source library to handle Polar heart rate monitor sound files?

Tags: java

Some of the Polar heart rate monitors can emit training session information using sound. The devices emit a sound like the modems used to do. Are there any Java based libraries to parse these sound files and extract the data? I prefer a Java library, but other implementations are fine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google found this: http://code.google.com/p/sonicread/. Haven't tried it myself.